# FCC testing for boards with programmable firmware

Tags: fcc, radiation

I'm curious how FCC conformity testing is done on PCBs that contain devices with programmable firmware. Specifically, boards that are designed to allow the end-user to reprogram the firmware (such as a microcontroller or FPGA). With that much flexibility and configurability of its final operation, how can you ensure the end-user won't do something wacky that could end up radiating in ways that weren't covered during the FCC tests?

Updating to specify: This is specifically focused on development kits, which is designed to be fully user programmable.

Answer (score 2):

If they are supposed to be reprogrammable, then they are tested with a worst-case configuration -- you try to build a program that violates the spec and run that.

Comment: What's the worst case? Making the uC or FPGA toggle a GPIO pin at its absolute fastest?

Comment: @SittinHawk, you'd pick a few IOs that are widely distributed outside (usually, clocks routed to other components) and frequency sweep them to see if there are frequencies that radiate off a lot.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but is that what's really required or done?  When we do EMC testing, it may not be with the final software or firmware, for instance.  WE don't go back and EMC test with the final configurations, much less a worst case configuration (assuming you can decide what that is).

Comment: You want at least all components to run, ideally at the same time (so you only need one pass per direction) and continuously, even if they wouldn't do that in normal operation -- that's your "worst case" configuration. If that works well, then the final firmware is expected to perform better, and any replacement firmware later on to at least not perform worse.

Comment: @SteveSh what's required is that in the field, as used by your customers, no single sample of your product interferes with the operation of a compliant device due to being out of compliance with FCC regulations.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on if the firmware could have direct impact on emissions.

If the firmware in question is directly controlling a radio in an 'Intentional Emitter' as defined in FCC Subpart J (for example, in an 802.11 router), then you'd need to re-test and have that test on file.

If the software update doesn't affect any Subpart J stuff, it would not require re-test.

However... if your update *did* cause your unit to suddenly start radiating more than limits as an *unintentional radiator*, the end user would be obliged to stop using it (or do something else to mitigate the interference) and they'd be yelling at you to fix it.

So your FCC testing should do its best to include as many use cases as possible. For example, if your device has variable clock rates, you need to test the 'worst' of them.

That all said, if your board is a development platform and can be regarded as a ‘subassembly’, the obligation for EMC compliance is ultimately on the buyer who is doing the system integration, not you.

More here: https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/398

Comment: I'm focused on unintentional radiation. And how do you determine the "worst"? Take for instance an FPGA GPIO driving a trace that goes to a pin header: You could write FPGA firmware to instantiate different PLL frequencies, and instantiate different counters that can further divide frequencies...a wide range of possibilities. Would you look at the length of that PCB trace and try to predict what frequency has the highest chance of radiation?

Comment: No, I’d do a sweep of all the possible target frequencies your design is expected to support, and choose the one that radiates the most.

Comment: @SittinHawk, have you noticed that nobody sells a product to the public that has that level of reprogrammability? People who buy FPGAs and re-sell them in products generally know (or should know) they need to test their product with the firmware running before they sell them.

Comment: If the FPGA is in a box and sold as an end product, or it’s designed to be put into a box as a standard form factor (like a PCIe card) it’s on you to take reasonable measures to ensure it won’t exceed your target limits. If it’s a dev board or a subsystem, forget it. It’s on the integrator to deal with that.

Comment: If you’re super concerned about narrowband noise coming from GPIOs, make sure the headers have adequate ground returns, consider ferrite beads in series, and possibly use spread-spectrum clocking. These will all help keep the EMI signature down.

Comment: @ThePhoton , "nobody sells a product to the public that has that level of reprogrammability?" What are you talking about? You can easily purchase any FPGA module that have pin headers, and it's specifically designed for the end user to have complete reprogrammability. Google FPGA Development Kit.

Comment: @SittinHawk A development kit is not meant to be sold to the public but to developers, who will have to test the product they develop for EMC after they have developed their firmware (and likely after they've re-designed the PCB to meet their product's specific needs.

Comment: @ThePhoton, I've purchased many FPGA development kits in the past as a member of "the public". What distinction was there that I am a developer versus a member of the general public curious about FPGAs? The device is a circuit board, operating in my house, which could very well have the capability to radiate and effect surrounding devices. Is there some kind of "development board" exception to FCC conformity tests?

Comment: @SittinHawk when you bought the dev kit you (implicitly or explicitly) told the seller that you understood it was not certified for EMC (FCC or CE or whatever) and that you (not they) would take responsibility for any interference you cause when you use it.

Comment: @ThePhoton, search "Digilent Basys 3" on Amazon right now. I see no such distinction, warning, or agreement as far as I can tell. Do you have any websites I can reference about the legalities of selling things that are not FCC certified, and just, passing off the responsibility to the end customer?

Comment: @SittinHawk "Implicitly" means it might not be stated directly. But have a look at paragraph 15 of Digilent's [Conditions of Sale](https://digilent.com/shop/legal-privacy/).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where (or which ETL) the device is tested at. But in many cases they will have the device run through some of it's 'modes' of operation and measure the radiation from the device.

Comment: I think you mean "NRTL" (nationally recognized testing laboratories), not "ETL" (Edison Test Lab, which is the mark of Intertek, which is only on example of an NRTL)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to The Proton, I have found an example of an Intel FPGA development board that has a disclaimer: See Appendix A of: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/ug/ug-c10-lp-eval-kit.pdf

The summary is that a development board may be considered a "subassembly", and I believe that exempts it from having to get FCC approval since the board's goal is "Evaluation of components". And it has a condition that the end user not use it for harmful interference: "Operation is subject to the condition that this product not cause harmful interference to licensed radio stations and that this product accept harmful interference."